# Why is my Contract interaction cost so high?

Tags: solidity

When interacting with the UI of my application, it says the cost of doing this interaction through metamask is 400 ether. I am using Ganache for testing which only allows you to have 100 ether. I am confused how come the cost is so high, and where in the truffle pet shop directory, would the files be located that affect this price, so I can bring it down for testing.

```
// Attempt to sign up user.
      rideshareInstance.joinRide(ride_number, {value: parseInt(payment * Math.pow(10,18)), from: coinbase})
      .then(function(result) {
        // If no error, login user.
        return browserHistory.push('/dashboard')
      })
      .catch(function(result) {
        // If error...
      })
    })
  })
}
```

When i change the values inside the Math.pow function, the contract code throws an exception. I believe that the values inside the Math.pow function are making the cost so high, but dont know how to change it.

Comment: Show your code please. Also, Ganache allows you as much as you want (up to `2 ** 256 - 1` wei). It's just a matter of configuration.

Comment: Not necessarily related to your problem, but the potential value of `Math.pow(10,18)` is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (which is equal to `2 ** 53 - 1`). So don't use it this way, and most certainly don't multiply it by `payment`. You can do something like `${payment}e+18` instead (encapsulated with a pair of `, and no need to use "parseInt" of course).

Comment: What's your contract code like? Also web3 provides [web3.utils.toWei](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.1/web3-utils.html#towei) to convert from ethers to wei without using `Math.pow`, for example `web3.utils.toWei('12', 'ether')`.